# Efficient insertion of complex data mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I try to insert some complex data into a mysql database but I have a problem with the performance of the implementation. My data looks like:

```
user1
  question1_1
    answer1_1_1
    answer1_1_2
    answer1_1_3
    ...
  question1_2
    answer1_2_1
    answer1_2_2
    ...
  ...
 user 2
 ...
```

For this I defined 3 tables in my database

```
users columns[userid, name,...]
questions columns[questionid, userid, questiontext]
answers columns[answerid, questionid, answertext]
```

I receive a whole bunch of data that I want to insert into the database. Because the tables are linked I now have an implementation that inserts the user, retrieves the ID and use this in the VALUES for the questions... It works but I receive 'Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded' because of the number of separate mysql insert statements.

My current code looks like:

```
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($users); $i++)
{
  $user = $users[$i];
  $sqlstr = "INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES ('".$users[$i]->id."')";

  mysql_query($sqlstr);
  $userid = mysql_insert_id(); 

  for ($j=0; $j<sizeof($user->question); $j++)
  {
    $question = $user->question[$j];

    $sqlstr = "INSERT INTO question (userid,creator,date) VALUES (".$userid.",'".$question->creator."','".$question->date."')";

    mysql_query($sqlstr);
    $questionid = mysql_insert_id(); 

    $rows = array();
    $sqlstr = "INSERT INTO answers (questionid,name,value) VALUES ";
    for ($k=0; $k<sizeof($question->answers); $k++)
    {
      $rows[] = "('".$questionid."','".$question->answers[$k]->name."','".$question->answers[$k]->value."')";
    }
    $sqlstr = $sqlstr.implode(',',$rows);
    mysql_query($sqlstr);
  }
}
```

How can I combine the separate insert statements into one big statementm, given that the ID of a previous insert is used in a next insert statement? I experimented with LAST_INSERT_ID() but this does not work as expected. It seems to reference the last ID of that table.

Or is there maybe another solution?

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` should return the ID of the last row that was inserted, regardless of the table it was inserted into. If you have having problems with it, you've probably got your statements in the wrong order. It's not possible to insert into multiple tables in a single statement (AFAIK) but you could write a MySQL [UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html) to do it. Don't forget you can `set_time_limit(0);` if you have a very long-running PHP script.

Comment: Please add your current PHP code to your question.

Comment: @DaveRandom You're right. I made I mistake with `LAST_INSERT_ID` but it is still useless for optimizing my code.
@nnichols I added my current slow code

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do to optimize this code, unless you explicitly provide the IDs in PHP. One thing you could do is to store the result of `sizeof` in a variable and then use the variable in the loop condition (so it doesn't have to check `sizeof` on every iteration), but I would highly doubt that will help much. As @DaveRandom suggested, you might just have to `set_time_limit(0);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the sql statements in a transaction. See [dev.mysql.com/doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html)
That will likely speed up the filling of the database, while still allowing you to keep issuing small single insert statements.

When you start a transaction, all disk access is suspended until you commit. This means that all your inserts will be written to disk in one go. Also all housekeeping updates then only need to be written once.

e.g.

```
mysql_query('START TRANSACTION');
<your code>
mysql_query('COMMIT');
```

*Note*: aborting a transaction (using `ROLLBACK`) can be surprisingly slow.